# Does Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect use OpenID, SAML 2.0 and LDAP Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, openid

I am trying to follow [this link](https://www.codeguru.com/azure/mvc-web-apps-azure/) for integration of Azure AD authentication. I am confused. Which method is this using internally?

Is it using Open ID, SAML 2.0 and LDAP authentication or just Open ID authentication?

I followed the link and the authentication is working fine but want to understand which method is this using internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses OpenID Connect. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oidc) has further explanations how the protocol works.